# Oracle cascade remove only when last reference was deleted

Tags: oracle, cascade

I am modeling a DB Shema for Oracle DB

There is an `Object Man`. 
`Object Man` references `Object Address`
There may be multiple `Man` referencing the same `Address`

How can I make Oracle cascade remove an entry corresponsing to `Object Address`, together with `Object Man` which was referencing it.  **But only if it was the last** `Man` **referencing the given** 'Address'?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a trigger.